# why I can't locate "_Alloc_traits" in STL source files with vim and ctags?

Tags: ctags

I have run `ctags -R` and I can locate every tag but `_Alloc_traits` with `Ctrl-]`.  It shows `E257: cstag : tag not found`.

Comment: Here is my ctags's version : `Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310`. And the STL is SGI C++ STL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the development of Exuberant Ctags is stagnant. I would advise you to try the version available [here](https://github.com/fishman/ctags). If the tag you're looking for is still not created please create an issue including the code where `_alloc_traits` is defined and a fixed update will very likely be quickly released.

Note: this version will fork into [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags) sometime in the near future because the original author of Exuberant Ctags is unwilling to cooperate for a code merge.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the ctags version you give. But it always shows `Notice: xcmd recognizes /usr/local/libexec/ctags/drivers/coffeetags is not available`,  even the tags file is created normally. And the `_Alloc_traits` tag is still not created. At last, I figure out the cause, it may be a bug, I'll add a issue. : )

Comment: I got the answer in github : use optino `-I`. `ctags -I__STL_NOTHROW -R`.